# CICD pipeline trigger:none meaning

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, cicd

I'm new to CICD pipeline and studying it with an existing pipeline used by our company.
In the main yaml script that runs the pipeline, I found **trigger:none**,
I looked up a document and it says it disables CI triggers..
but I'm not really sure what it means. it disables triggering pipeline but why do we need it and why do we need to disable it?

I know this could be really a basic question, but would appreciate it if someone could help me understand how it works.

Thank you!

Comment: Have used fake trigger branch called 'NONE' to temporarily disable CI on certain builds.  There are other better ways if you don't want CI at all for a build, but mainly that trick is for a temporary halt to CI.  Why you want to do that depends on the situation.  Maybe you want to relieve stress on the build agent when a bunch of people need to check in very fast and merge/PR in sequence.  That sort of thing.

Comment: thanks for your response @TomServo  just wondering if it is for preventing pipelines from being executed every time we update them or yaml files in the same branch?

Comment: The method I mentioned is to prevent a single pipeline that normally triggers from a branch like 'dev' to not trigger automatically at all.    We just comment out the normal trigger branch and uncomment 'NONE'.  Then the CI won't run because branch 'NONE' doesn't exist, and so people have to run the pipeline manually.  That's all.  We switch it back when whatever situation causing this is resolved.

Answer (score 2):

As the official document mentioned:

[Disabling the CI trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#disabling-the-ci-trigger)

`trigger: none` will disable the CI trigger.

To be honest, I always use `trigger: none` during the test step of my pipeline.

If nothing is set, the pipeline will be triggered whenever there is any change within the branch.

---

***The fundamental reason for using this is that what I am doing is not necessary to consider the trigger.***

For example, I need to process a configuration file, I use a script to parse and process it, I may need to make some changes to the configuration file to test the entire pipeline logic, when I don't design the trigger specific content, I just need to change the configuration file, or add a file, the pipeline will be triggered immediately.

But I only focus on the logic part at this time, the trigger is not important in this case, of course I can "seriously" write a complete and detailed CI trigger, but it is not necessary, I only care about the logic part, `trigger: none` only spends me one second.

This allows me to focus on the entire pipeline process and writing code, without having to think about how to write a suitable CI trigger to filter when to trigger the pipeline.